# Reduce array-length if same value occurs twice in a row

Tags: c, breadth-first-search

I've got two arrays which are populated with x & y coordinates, which are integers.

Now i want to reduce the array so that if

```
arrayX[5] = 100 //first occurance of this value
arrayX[6] = 100 //same
arrayX[7] = 100 //same
arrayX[8] = 100 //same
arrayX[9] = 125 //NEW VALUE! Most likely a turn
```

while

```
arrayY[5] = 350 //will be kept due to first entry of this coordinate
arrayY[6] = 375 //will be removed due to X
arrayY[7] = 400 //will be removed due to X
arrayY[8] = 425 //will be removed due to X
arrayY[9] = 450 //Then we proceed to look ahead from here
```

The Output should be:

```
(ArrayX[5] = 100, ArrayY[5] = 350)
(ArrayX[8] = 100, ArrayY[8] = 425)
//ArrayX[6] -> ArrayX[7] Will now have been deleted
//proceed to look ahead for new redundant values
```

only one entry into the array should be made where the coordinates are redundant.

As of now: my arrays look like this (LIFO):

```
(X: 450.000000, Y: 300.000000) //Last pos
(X: 425.000000, Y: 300.000000)
(X: 400.000000, Y: 300.000000)
(X: 375.000000, Y: 300.000000)
(X: 350.000000, Y: 300.000000)
(X: 325.000000, Y: 300.000000)
(X: 300.000000, Y: 300.000000)
(X: 275.000000, Y: 300.000000)
(X: 250.000000, Y: 300.000000)
(X: 225.000000, Y: 300.000000)
(X: 200.000000, Y: 300.000000)
(X: 175.000000, Y: 300.000000)
(X: 150.000000, Y: 300.000000)
(X: 125.000000, Y: 300.000000) //First pos
```

As you can see, there are a lot of redundant coordinates on how to reach the goal coordinate.

We only want to check where turns occur (new value-pair entry) and start and finish coordinate.

*(see below for further visual explanation on this)*

Desired reduced array (in this case):

```
(X: 450.000000, Y: 300.000000) //Last pos
(X: 125.000000, Y: 300.000000) //First pos
//all repeating nodes have been removed from the array
```

Graphical explanation ● = fastest way to goal (*the arrays (**x,y**)*):

The dots ( ● ) are our arrays, visually represented. Since our arrays contain coordinates as stated above. X, Y results in the ● appearing in that place

```
@@@ @@@ @@@ @@@ @@@ @@@ @@@ @@@ @@@ @@@ @@@ @@@ @@@ @@@ @@@ @@@ @@@ @@@ @@@ @@@ @@@ @@@ @@@ @@@  
@@@  !   !   !   !   !   !   !   !   !   !   !   !   !   !   !   !   !   !   !   !   !   !  @@@
@@@  !   !                                                                           !   !  @@@
@@@  !   !                                                                           !   !  @@@
@@@  !   !                                   14  S   14                              !   !  @@@
@@@  !   !                               14  13  ●   13  14                          !   !  @@@
@@@  !   !                           14  13  12  ●   12  13  14                      !   !  @@@
@@@  !   !                       14  13  12  11  ●   11  12  13  14                  !   !  @@@
@@@  !   !                   14  13  12  11  10  ●   10  11  12  13  14              !   !  @@@
@@@  !   !               14  13  12  11  10   9  ●    9  10  11  12  13  14          !   !  @@@
@@@  !   !           14  13  12  11  10   9   8  ●    8   9  10  11  12  13  14      !   !  @@@
@@@  !   !       14  13  12  11  10   9   8   7  ●    7   8   9  10  11  12  13  14  !   !  @@@
@@@  !   !   14  13  12  11  10   9   8   7   6  ●    6   7   8   9  10  11  12  13  !   !  @@@
@@@  !   !   13  12  11  10   9   8   7   6   5  ●    5   6   7   8   9  10  11  12  !   !  @@@
@@@  !   !   12  11  10   9   8   7   6   5   4  ●    4   5   6   7   8   9  10  11  !   !  @@@
@@@  !   !   11  10   9   8   7   6   5   4   3  ●    3   4   5   6   7   8   9  10  !   !  @@@
@@@  !   !   10   9   8   7   6   5   4   3   2  ●    2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9  !   !  @@@
@@@  !   !    9   8   7   6   5   4   3   2   1  G    1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8  !   !  @@@
@@@  !   !   10   9   8   7   6   5   4   3   2   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9  !   !  @@@
@@@  !   !   11  10   9   8   7   6   5   4   3   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9  10  !   !  @@@
@@@  !   !   !   !   !   !   !   !   !   !   !   !   !   !   !   !   !   !   !   !   !   !  @@@
@@@  !   !   !   !   !   !   !   !   !   !   !   !   !   !   !   !   !   !   !   !   !   !  @@@
@@@ @@@ @@@ @@@ @@@ @@@ @@@ @@@ @@@ @@@ @@@ @@@ @@@ @@@ @@@ @@@ @@@ @@@ @@@ @@@ @@@ @@@ @@@ @@@
```

With Array Reduction:

```
@@@ @@@ @@@ @@@ @@@ @@@ @@@ @@@ @@@ @@@ @@@ @@@ @@@ @@@ @@@ @@@ @@@ @@@ @@@ @@@ @@@ @@@ @@@ @@@  
@@@  !   !   !   !   !   !   !   !   !   !   !   !   !   !   !   !   !   !   !   !   !   !  @@@
@@@  !   !                                                                           !   !  @@@
@@@  !   !                                                                           !   !  @@@
@@@  !   !                                   14  S   14                              !   !  @@@
@@@  !   !                               14  13  ●  13  14                          !   !  @@@
@@@  !   !                           14  13  12  11   12  13  14                      !   !  @@@
@@@  !   !                       14  13  12  11  10   11  12  13  14                  !   !  @@@
@@@  !   !                   14  13  12  11  10  9   10  11  12  13  14              !   !  @@@
@@@  !   !               14  13  12  11  10   9  8    9  10  11  12  13  14          !   !  @@@
@@@  !   !           14  13  12  11  10   9   8  7    8   9  10  11  12  13  14      !   !  @@@
@@@  !   !       14  13  12  11  10   9   8   7  6    7   8   9  10  11  12  13  14  !   !  @@@
@@@  !   !   14  13  12  11  10   9   8   7   6  5    6   7   8   9  10  11  12  13  !   !  @@@
@@@  !   !   13  12  11  10   9   8   7   6   5  4    5   6   7   8   9  10  11  12  !   !  @@@
@@@  !   !   12  11  10   9   8   7   6   5   4  3    4   5   6   7   8   9  10  11  !   !  @@@
@@@  !   !   11  10   9   8   7   6   5   4   3  2    3   4   5   6   7   8   9  10  !   !  @@@
@@@  !   !   10   9   8   7   6   5   4   3   2  ●    2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9  !   !  @@@
@@@  !   !    9   8   7   6   5   4   3   2   1  G    1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8  !   !  @@@
@@@  !   !   10   9   8   7   6   5   4   3   2   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9  !   !  @@@
@@@  !   !   11  10   9   8   7   6   5   4   3   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9  10  !   !  @@@
@@@  !   !   !   !   !   !   !   !   !   !   !   !   !   !   !   !   !   !   !   !   !   !  @@@
@@@  !   !   !   !   !   !   !   !   !   !   !   !   !   !   !   !   !   !   !   !   !   !  @@@
@@@ @@@ @@@ @@@ @@@ @@@ @@@ @@@ @@@ @@@ @@@ @@@ @@@ @@@ @@@ @@@ @@@ @@@ @@@ @@@ @@@ @@@ @@@ @@@
```

Exceptions to the array-reduction are when we come at a turning point like this:

```
●
●
●
●
● ● ● ● ●
```

that should be reduced to:

```
●



●       ●
```

Current Code:

When a goal-node is found, a counter is incremented and the coordinate is stored within that array-counter position.

```
  double arrayX[counter]; //this is where the coordinates are stored
  double arrayY[counter]; // -||- 

  //My attempt at reduction
  for(int i=counter; i > 0; i--){ //checking array
    for(int j=i;j < counter;j++){ 
        if(arrayY[counter] != arrayY[counter+2] && arrayX[counter] != arrayX[counter+2]){ //IF x != x+2 that means we have a new value at x+1
          arrayY[counter] =  arrayY[counter+1];
          arrayX[counter] =  arrayX[counter+1];
          counter--;
        }
    }
  }
```

This however only gets me the first pair, and then 0 everywhere else.

Any further code most likely irrelevant since i'm working in an APK-environment. The code above are the two arrays that need reduction based on the values they have.
function-code to generate path(snippet):

```
    while(maxValue  != MAP_GOAL){                      //while we are not at the goal
      n1             = GetCellState(grid,bestCell.i,bestCell.j-1); 
      n2             = GetCellState(grid,bestCell.i,bestCell.j+1);
      n3             = GetCellState(grid,bestCell.i-1,bestCell.j);
      n4             = GetCellState(grid,bestCell.i+1,bestCell.j);
      if((n1 < maxValue) && (n1 >= 0)){
          maxValue   = n1;
          nextCell.i = bestCell.i;
          nextCell.j = bestCell.j-1;
      }
      if((n2 < maxValue) && (n2 >= 0)){
          maxValue   = n2;
          nextCell.i = bestCell.i;
          nextCell.j = bestCell.j+1;
      }
      if((n3 < maxValue) && (n3 >= 0)){
          maxValue   = n3;
          nextCell.i = bestCell.i-1;
          nextCell.j = bestCell.j;
      }
      if((n4 < maxValue) && (n4 >= 0)){
          maxValue   = n4;
          nextCell.i = bestCell.i+1;
          nextCell.j = bestCell.j;

      }
        Push           (Path,nextCell);
        bestCell.i   = nextCell.i;
        bestCell.j   = nextCell.j;
        bestCell.h_value = 0;
        ChangeCellState(grid,bestCell.i,bestCell.j,-9); // mark path with custom sign
        counter++;

    }                                                   //end while
  }else{
    printf("\nPath was NOT found, terminating...");
    exit(1);
  }                                                    // end if-else

  printf("\nPath FOUND!\n");
  //expanding the cells

  double arrayX[counter];
  double arrayY[counter];
   /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
   //          THIS IS WHERE THE REDUCTION SHOULD TAKE PLACE  //
   /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
Cell temp;
  for(int i=0; i < counter; i++){
    temp      = Pop(Path);
    arrayX[i] = temp.i * CELLSIZE;
    arrayY[i] = temp.j * CELLSIZE;
  }

  for(int i=0;i < (sizeof(arrayX) / sizeof(arrayX[0])); i++){
    printf("(X: %f, Y: %f) \n",arrayX[i], arrayY[i]);
  }
```

TL;DR - How would i reduce array-pairs that are linked to each-other when one of the arrays has multiple entries of the same value.

Comment: i don't understand your graph explanation or the TLDR version...

Comment: @HuStmpHrrr Can you please elaborate on *what exactly* you have a hard time understanding and i'll try to explain it in further detail :)

Comment: it might really be a simple problem but it's a too long post with your incomplete customized objects and the graph is unclear. if it can indeed be understood easily, you probably can give a single example so that it's more accessible.

Comment: @HuStmpHrrr The dots ( ● ) are our arrays, visually represented. Since our arrays contain coordinates as stated above. X, Y results in the  ● appearing in that place.

Comment: @HuStmpHrrr General problem: Reduce multiple entries of the same value occuring twice or more. Look at the reduced array-print at the top. As you can see we have multiple entries of `Y: 300` in a row. This is not very effective.  As there is no new information on these entries. It's always `Y = 300`. While X may vary, i only want to keep the first and last entry of X and it's counter-pair in Y, while Y = 300 (look in the question on the formatted array-list).

Comment: what if X goes down? say `(450, 300)` then `(400, 300)`, do you want to keep `(450, 300)`?

Comment: @HuStmpHrrr Correct, I want to keep the first entry, then all successor entries that are redundant, i want to remove.

Comment: It looks like you are trying a form of A* pathfinding with only cardinal directions, but you only want to keep track of the steps that require a change in direction.  That sound accurate?

Comment: @ChristianGibbons While A* would be nice, it isn't quite what i want. I just want to reduce redundant nodes. While the arrays already have been populated, i just want to remove the X / Y values that are repeating themselves in a row and remove their counter-pair in the other array as well.

Comment: Removing elements from the interior of an array is a bit of a pain.  Maybe you could create a new array where the nodes you actually want to keep will get copied to and then you can ditch the old array.  Personally, I'd also probably keep the x and y values in a struct to keep coordinates together and have an array of coordinates.  Then search through the coordinate array and only copy over the coordinates to the new array in which fit your criteria.

Comment: i'd imagine this can be managed by a state machine looking forward to handle all 4 cases: x increasing, x decreasing, y increasing, y decreasing

Comment: @ChristianGibbons Yeah that would work, but i have no idea on how to create such a function. I've tried for hours now and i seem to only get further and further away.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this in just one loop.

```
//x = [100,100,100,100,125]
//y = [350,375,400,425,450]

int z = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
  if (i == n - 1 || z == 0 || (x[i] != x[i + 1] || x[i] != x[z - 1]) && (y[i] != y[i + 1] || y[i] != y[z - 1])) {
      x[z] = x[i];
      y[z] = y[i];
      z++;
  }
}
```

This should give you:

```
//x = [100, 100, 125, 100, 125]
//y = [350, 425, 450, 425, 450]
//z = 3
```

Now just delete the rest of the elements of indices >= z and that should leave you with:

```
//x = [100, 100, 125]
//y = [350, 425, 450]
```

Comment: This is best answer.

Comment: @Joel: It should be very easy to adopt your own naming conventions, so if you think this answer works, just accept it. You will find that this answer is essentially the same as mine, except that all conditions are crammed into a single if and that this code will access `x[-1]` or `y[-1]`, which is illegal, but can be fixed easily.

Comment: I tried to implement this solution, but unable to do so. My arrays are now: `(X: 0.000000, Y: 0.000000)
(X: 0.000000, Y: 0.000000)
(X: 0.000000, Y: 0.000000)
(X: 0.000000, Y: 0.000000)
(X: 0.000000, Y: 0.000000)
(X: 0.000000, Y: 0.000000)
(X: 0.000000, Y: 0.000000)
(X: 0.000000, Y: 0.000000)
(X: 0.000000, Y: 0.000000)
(X: 0.000000, Y: 0.000000)
(X: 0.000000, Y: 0.000000)
(X: 0.000000, Y: 0.000000)
(X: 150.000000, Y: 300.000000)
(X: 125.000000, Y: 300.000000)`

0,0 is actually a position coordinate. also, i probably have missed something since i can't get it to work as above :/

Comment: @Joel: I added a check for z == 0 but that shouldn't change the outcome. I'm not sure why you're getting that result. Check out this link https://ideone.com/wkYS3b and read the stdout at the bottom.

Comment: @anomaaly hmm. now i got: `(X: 450.000000, Y: 300.000000)
(X: 125.000000, Y: 300.000000)
(X: 400.000000, Y: 300.000000)
(X: 375.000000, Y: 300.000000)
(X: 350.000000, Y: 300.000000)

(X: 325.000000, Y: 300.000000)
(X: 300.000000, Y: 300.000000)
(X: 275.000000, Y: 300.000000)
(X: 250.000000, Y: 300.000000)
(X: 225.000000, Y: 300.000000)
(X: 200.000000, Y: 300.000000)
(X: 175.000000, Y: 300.000000)
(X: 150.000000, Y: 300.000000)
(X: 125.000000, Y: 300.000000)`it seems that it has got the first two lines correct. (which is what the end result should be, but it doesnt remove the rest

Comment: @Joel yeah, notice how I only printed up to z, not the entire array. It's trivial to delete the rest of the elements where the index >= z. Does that make sense?

Comment: @anomaaly look here: https://ideone.com/OaAq7h the problem is that you are not actually printing what's in the arrays. (that's why your solution appears to be working). they are still populated with the values, only re-arranged.

Comment: @anomaaly It is not trivial since i'm sending away the arrays into the APK. x) Maybe i should have been more clear on this. I can try to loop through the arrays one more time based on z and assign those to a new array.

Comment: @Joel It's not trivial to delete elements from an array? for (int i = z; i < n; i++) {
    x[i] = '\0';
    y[i] = '\0';
  }

Comment: @anomaaly See: https://ideone.com/OGDXrZ Post that into an answer and i'll approve it for you :) (you did all the work, credit where credit is due) Thank you so much for all your help!

Comment: @Joel looks like you've got it

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps I'm missing something here, but you couldn't you use the regular technique for filtering an array:

```
// given: array a[n] of length n

int k = 0;

for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    if (keep(a[i]) a[k++] = a[i];
}

// k is the new array length
```

In your case, you must keep the first and last elements and you also need to look one step back and one step ahead. The following function compacts an array of point coordinates. The array initially has size `n`; the possibly reduced size is retuened from the function:

```
struct point {
    int x, y;
};

int compact_points(struct point pt[], int n)
{
    int k = 1;                     // keep the first point

    if (n < 3) return n;

    for (int i = 1; i < n - 1; i++) {
        int x = pt[i].x;
        int y = pt[i].y;

        // skip middle points of three equal x or y coords
        if (x == pt[k - 1].x && x == pt[i + 1].x) continue;
        if (y == pt[k - 1].y && y == pt[i + 1].y) continue;

        // copy corner points
        pt[k++] = pt[i];
    }

    pt[k++] = pt[n - 1];           // add last point

    return k;
}
```

That code uses a struct, but it's easy to modify it so that it uses two arrays:

```
int compact_arrays(int *x, int *y, int n)
{
    int k = 1;

    if (n < 3) return n;

    for (int i = 1; i < n - 1; i++) {
        if (x[i] == x[k - 1] && x[i] == x[i + 1]) continue;
        if (y[i] == y[k - 1] && y[i] == y[i + 1]) continue;

        x[k] = x[i];
        y[k] = y[i];
        k++;
    }

    x[k] = x[n - 1];
    y[k] = y[n - 1];

    return k + 1;
}
```

Make sure that you keep the return value, because it's the new array size:

```
int main(void)
{
    int x[14] = { 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5 };
    int y[14] = { 0, 1, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 4 };
    int n = 14;

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) printf("%d, %d\n", x[i], y[i]);
    puts("");

    n = compact_arrays(x, y, 14);

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) printf("%d, %d\n", x[i], y[i]);
    puts("");

    return 0;
}
```

You could also compact the array as you poulate it: When the arrays have more than one element and either the x or y value you add is equal to the x or y value of the last two elements in the array, overwrite the last element. Otherwise, append to the array:

```
enum {
    arrayMax = 20
};    

struct array {
    int n;
    int x[arrayMax];
    int y[arrayMax];
};

void array_append(struct array *a, int x, int y)
{
    if (a->n > 1) {
        int n1 = a->n - 1;
        int n2 = n1 - 1;

        if ((x == a->x[n1] && x == a->x[n2])
         || (y == a->y[n1] && y == a->y[n2]))
        {
            a->x[n1] = x;
            a->y[n1] = y;
            return;
        }
    }

    if (a->n < arrayMax) {
        a->x[a->n] = x;
        a->y[a->n] = y;
        a->n++;
    }
}

int main(void)
{
    int x[14] = { 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5 };
    int y[14] = { 0, 1, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 4 };
    struct array a = {0};

    for (int i = 0; i < 14; i++) {
        array_append(&a, x[i], y[i]);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < a.n; i++) printf("%d, %d\n", a.x[i], a.y[i]);
    puts("");

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I'll have a go at this. The reason for using arrays and not structs is that i'm adding them to a struct  just after this step. I need to convert them to the APK-values before they can be accepted. Hence the arrays.

Comment: Well, if you keep the arrays synchronised that should work as well, of course.

Comment: Question: what is `n` here? Since you said that k is my counter, i'm not quite sure what this is supposed to be?

Comment: `n` is the length of the original array. `k` is the length of the array after throwing out the intermediate points.